# jquery datepicker not working with windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, datepicker

jquery datepicker not working with windows phone 7. It is working with IE 9. In phone keyboard will appear instead of datepicker.

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#from-date" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script> 

  <input type="text" name="departure" id="from-date" value=""  novalidate="true" />
```